# GCC inline - push address, not its value to stack

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly, att

I'm experimenting with GCC's inline assembler (I use MinGW, my OS is Win7).
Right now I'm only getting some basic C stdlib functions to work. I'm generally familiar with the Intel syntax, but new to AT&T.

The following code works nice:

```
char localmsg[] = "my local message";
asm("leal %0, %%eax" : "=m" (localmsg));
asm("push %eax");
asm("call %0" : : "m" (puts));
asm("add $4,%esp");
```

That LEA seems redundant, however, as I can just push the value straight onto the stack. Well, due to what I believe is an AT&T peculiarity, doing this:

```
asm("push %0" : "=m" (localmsg));
```

will generate the following assembly code in the final executable:

```
PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+1F]
```

So instead of pushing the address to my string, its contents were pushed because the "pointer" was "dereferenced", in C terms. This obviously leads to a crash.

I believe this is just GAS's normal behavior, but I was unable to find any information on how to overcome this. I'd appreciate any help.

P.S. I know this is a trivial question to those who are experienced in the matter. I expect to be downvoted, but I've just spent 45 minutes looking for a solution and found nothing.

P.P.S. I realize the proper way to do this would be to call `puts( )` in the C code. This is for purely educational/experimental reasons.

Comment: does `asm("push %0" : "=m" (&localmsg));` work?

Comment: @markgz No, it complains that 'lvalue required in asm statement'. It wouldn't make much sense anyway, I think, since localmsg is already a pointer.

Comment: Why are you marking localmsg as an output operand?

Comment: @MarcGlisse My mistake, I didn't understand that the first colon is always for output, regardless of the modifier. This has no effect on my problem, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While inline asm is always a bit tricky, calling functions from it is particularly challenging.  Not something I would suggest for a "getting to known inline asm" project.  If you haven't already, I suggest looking through the very latest inline asm [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).  A lot of work has been done to try to explain how inline asm works.

That said, here are some thoughts:

1) Using multiple asm statements like this is a bad idea.  As the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html#Basic-Asm) say: *Do not expect a sequence of asm statements to remain perfectly consecutive after compilation. If certain instructions need to remain consecutive in the output, put them in a single multi-instruction asm statement.*

2) Directly modifying registers (like you are doing with eax) without letting gcc know you are doing so is also a bad idea.  You should either use register constraints (so gcc can pick its own registers) or clobbers to let gcc know you are stomping on them.

3) When a function (like puts) is called, while some registers must have their values restored before returning, some registers can be treated as scratch registers by the called function (ie modified and not restored before returning).  As I mentioned in #2, having your asm modify registers without informing gcc is a very bad idea.  If you know the ABI for the function you are calling, you can add its scratch registers to the asm's clobber list.

4) While in this specific example you are using a constant string, as a general rule, when passing asm pointers to strings, structs, arrays, etc, you are likely to need the "memory" clobber to ensure that any pending writes to memory are performed before starting to execute your asm.

5) Actually, the `lea` is doing something very important.  The value of esp is not known at compile time, so it's not like you can perform `push $12345`.  Someone needs to compute (esp + the offset of localmsg) before it can be pushed on the stack.  Also, see second example below.

6) If you prefer intel format (and what right-thinking person wouldn't?), you can use -masm=intel.

Given all this, my first cut at this code looks like this.  Note that this does NOT clobber puts' scratch registers.  That's left as an exercise...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  const char localmsg[] = "my local message";

  int result;

  /* Use 'volatile' since 'result' is usually not going to get used,
     which might tempt gcc to discard this asm statement as unneeded. */

  asm volatile ("push %[msg] \n\t"   /* Push the address of the string. */
                "call %[puts] \n \t" /* Call the print function. */
                "add $4,%%esp"       /* Clean up the stack. */

                : "=a" (result) /* The result code from puts. */
                : [puts] "m" (puts), [msg] "r" (localmsg)
                : "memory", "esp");

   printf("%d\n", result);
}
```

True this doesn't avoid the `lea` due to #5.  However, if that's **really** important, try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
const char localmsg[] = "my local message";

int main()
{

  int result;

  /* Use 'volatile' since 'result' is usually not going to get used. */

  asm volatile ("push %[msg] \n\t" /* Push the address of the string. */
                "call %[puts] \n \t" /* Call the print function. */
                "add $4,%%esp"       /* Clean up the stack. */

                : "=a" (result) /* The result code. */
                : [puts] "m" (puts), [msg] "i" (localmsg)
                : "memory", "esp");

   printf("%d\n", result);
}
```

As a global, the address of localmsg is now knowable at compile time (ok, I'm simplifying a bit), the asm produced looks like this:

```
push $__ZL8localmsg
call _puts
add $4,%esp
```

Tada.

Comment: Excellent answer. I do very much prefer Intel's syntax, but I'm not sure how to get it to work with the extended syntax and variables.

Comment: The doc link I gave you to the inline asm docs talks about how to work with variables (w/many examples).  If you are coming from MS's compiler, you need to forget about the idea of using symbol names within the asm.  (Virtually) all variables need to be specified as either inputs or outputs.  As for "getting intel to work", there's nothing to it.  Consider this (useless) asm statement: `asm("movl $0, %eax");`.  Compiled with `gcc foo.cpp`, it will compile without error.  Compiled with `gcc -masm=intel foo.cpp`, it will error unless you change it to intel syntax: `asm("mov eax, 0");`

Comment: Yup, but I mean the "parameters" "passed" to the inline ASM code, like in the example you were helping me with. It's [name] or %0 in ATT, what should I do to get it working in Intel?

Comment: Exactly the same thing ([name] or %0).  These aren't artifacts of att, they are just how gcc gets parameters into the proper places in the asm.  Think of the string in the first parameter as the template to fprintf.  When the compiler compiles the asm statement, it just takes all the %0 and %[name], substitutes the stuff from the constraints and outputs the resulting string to the assembler.

Comment: OK, that works. However, GCC will still produce ATT code after I switch to Intel with ".intel_syntax", for example push %[msg] becomes push %eax, which of course won't work in my .intel_syntax block. I know that GCC blindly pastes my code into its generated asm without understanding it, but how can I force it to use Intel where I want? I know about -masm=intel, but surely there must be a different way?

Comment: Using `.intel_syntax` doesn't "switch" the c compiler to using intel format.  As far as c is concerned, that's just another arbitrary string that gets output to the assembler (which DOES change how the assembler interprets code).  If you want to change the format of the code output by the compiler, you need to use -masm.  In theory you can wrap all your asm strings with `.intel_syntax/.att_syntax`, but that may introduce other issues.  What's wrong with using -masm?  Or are you writing public headers?  It's possible for one asm statement to support both: asm("{mov $0, %0|mov %0, 0}" ...

Comment: There's nothing really wrong with -masm=intel, I'm just experimenting. Anyway, thanks, you've answered everything :)